# Почему scrollTop постоянно скролит в самый вверх страницы? JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, прокрутка

Использую такой код:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#rakenduse').offset().top}, 2000);
```

Нужно проскролить к элементу `$('#rakenduse')`, но скролит постоянно вверх страницы.

Также:

```
console.log($('#rakenduse').offset());
```

выводит `{top: 0, left: 0}` , хотя элемент находится явно не вверху страницы:

[image: Расположения элемента]

Comment: Хорошо бы разметку добавить к вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убедитесь что у Вас **достаточно места снизу** для того что бы скролл сработал корректно:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#test").offset().top}, 2000)
}

$("button").on("click", handleClick)
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#test {
  display: table;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

button:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Scroll to DIV</button>
<div id="test">Test DIV with margin-top: 200px;</div>
<button>Scroll to DIV</button>
```

*В остальном Ваш код работает корректно, другая возможная причина это расчет позиции `offset`. Если использовать нативные методы, то реальный `offset` обычно приходиться считать самостоятельно, однако, поскольку Вы используете jQuery и его метод [offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/), то проблем с расчетом из за вложенности быть не должно.*

Comment: " то реальный offset обычно приходиться считать самостоятельно " - было бы неплохо узнать как это правильно делать

Comment: @PHPWork попробуйте поиграть со свойством [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) (JS) в консоли, если у Ваш элемент будет находиться глубоко (вложенность) то данной свойство не покажет  расстояние до верха документа, а только до родителя. Т.е Вам придется сложить несколько значений что бы получить требуемый результат